# fluent Python book, example 2.15

Tags: python

I'm reading Luciano Ramalho's book fluent Python, and he writes that if we write code like this:

```
>>>t=(1,2,[30,40])
>>>t[2]+=[50,60]
```

, then we will get :

> a. t becomes (1, 2, [30, 40, 50, 60]).
>   b. TypeError is raised with
>   the message 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.

I've totally understood this.

But one of his readers then said that if we write code like:

```
>>>t=(1,2,[30,40])
>>>t[2].extend([50,60])
```

, this will not raise a `TypeError` message at this time. I want to know why this is happening.

And if possible, try to describe the execution of the code with pictures for me.
Appreciate it!

Comment: On your first line, `t2` is not `t`, so it seems the code is incomplete to generate the error you mentioned.

Comment: Nvm. I understood now -- `t = (1,2,[30,40])` then `t[2]+=[50,60]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may not be 100% correct technically, but I will try to explain as intuitively as possible.
First case:

```
>>>t=(1,2,[30,40])
>>>t[2]+=[50,60]
```

Let's see what's happening:

When you access `t[2]` it picks up the list `[30,40]`, now while performing `+=` operation, it adds `[50,60]` to `t[2]` in a specific way:

`t[2] = t[2].__iadd__([50,60])`

Now the right hand side is valid, that is why the list that `t[2]` points to changes after the operation, but the assignment part is the problem, tuple does not support `item assignment`.

Second case:

```
>>>t=(1,2,[30,40])
>>>t[2].extend([50,60])
```

Here, there are no copies involved, hence there is no need to assign the copy back to `t[2]` you are just extending the list that `t[2]` refers to.

Let's see some different examples:

```
>>> x = [30,40]
>>> t1 = (1,2,x)
>>> t1
(1, 2, [30, 40])
>>> x += [50,60]
>>> x
[30, 40, 50, 60]
>>> t1
(1, 2, [30, 40, 50, 60])
```

Here, `x` points to a list `[30, 40]`. And `t1` contains that reference. Now you can modify `x` independently, because you are just modifying the list, and now the list that `x` referred to has become `[30,40,50,60]`, as `t1[2]` contains the reference to that same list, it now shows `[30,40,50,60]`, so not at all surprising.

Another example:

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2, [30, 40])
>>> x = t1[2]
>>> x += [50,60]
>>> x
[30, 40, 50, 60]
>>> t1
(1, 2, [30, 40, 50, 60])
```

Here, `t1[2]` refers to a list `[30,40]`, and you decide to give another name (`x`) to the same list. Now you modify the list, that `x` referred to, there are no restriction to that, `list`s are mutable objects, so you do not get any errors, and as `t[2]` pointed to the same list, you are not trying to store another modified list in `t[2]`, it's only that the list that `t[2]` was pointing to, itself has got changed.

Finally, if we look at the bytecode disassembly, it will be clearer:

```
>>> import dis

>>> def f1():
...     t = (1,2,[30,40])
...     t[2]+=[50,60]
...     return t

>>> def f2():
...     t = (1,2,[30,40])
...     t[2].extend([50,60])
...     return t

>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (30)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (40)
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (t)

  3          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             18 DUP_TOP_TWO
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR
             22 LOAD_CONST               5 (50)
             24 LOAD_CONST               6 (60)
             26 BUILD_LIST               2      
             28 INPLACE_ADD              # t[2].__iadd__([50,60])
             30 ROT_THREE
             32 STORE_SUBSCR             # tries to store; t[2] = t[2].__iadd__([50,60])

  4          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             36 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(f2)

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (30)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (40)
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (t)

  3          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 LOAD_METHOD              0 (extend)  # loads the same list in t[2]
             22 LOAD_CONST               5 (50)
             24 LOAD_CONST               6 (60)
             26 BUILD_LIST               2
             28 CALL_METHOD              1
             30 POP_TOP                              # no store calls

  4          32 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: _"now while performing += operation, it first creates a copy of the list "_ I'm pretty sure that is not true. If you cast `t` to list (just to allow the inplace add to go through) and keep a reference `t2 = t[2]` and then do `t[2] += whatever` you'll find that `t2`, not a copy, is modified.

Comment: Yes, the fact that `t[2]` gets modified is the reason why `t[2]` becomes `[30,40,50,60]` afterwards, even when it raises `TypeError`, but it also tries to store a list `[30,40,50,60]` in `t[2]` (`32 STORE_SUBSCR`) that gives rise to the problem.

Comment: Not _a_ list, the very same list. Apart from `[50,60]` no new list is created. The back assignment is only there because inplace add is not guaranteed to be inplace. For example if `t[2]` were not a list but a number, _then_ `t[2] += some other number` would create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

```
t=(1,2,[30,40])
t2 += [50,60]
```

This will not work because t2 references a variable that does not exist

```
t=(1,2,[30,40])
t += [50,60]
```

This will also not work because you can not extend a tuple with a list, you will get an error such as this `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`

```
t=(1,2,[30,40])
t[2] += [50,60]
```

This works because you are extending the list that is the third element inside of the tuple. If you then print the tuple it will look like this: `(1, 2, [30, 40, 50, 60])`
Note that tuples are generally immutable, this means that you ca not append values once it is created. But then something like this:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t2 = (4,5,6)
t3 = t + t2
```

Works, because you are creating a new tuple by adding the previous two, but you are not changing them. I hope this clarifies this a bit.

Also, in some cases, if they contain objects that are mutable then they are also considered mutable (Correct me if I'm wrong!).